# How to fill in a column with a function of another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I realize the `day_charge` column can be produced by a a function of `day_mins`.
Precisely: `day_charge = day_mins * .17`

There are `NaN` values in the `day_charge` column, how would I fill in the `NaN` values with the above function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill in missing values:

```
df['day_charge'] = df['day_charge'].fillna(df['day_mins'] * 0.17)
```

Comment: This will only update those rows that are NaN with this function, not the entire column.

Comment: I didn't downvote... but I think OP's question is a bit weird at this point, and unclear. Do they want every value replaced or just the NaNs? The `I realize the day_charge column is can be produced by a a function of day_mins` comment seems to suggest the other.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Yeh no problem. I guess I took  the *can be* produced literally. It doesn't say *is required to be*. The truth is I was too lazy to take my calculator to check the few rows we have.

Answer (score 3):

Since your column is always `day_mins * .17`, in your case it might be easier and faster to replace the whole column:

```
df['day_charge'] = df['day_mins'] * 0.17
```

But @jpp's solution actually addresses your question of how to fill in `NaN`s with a given function.